# Moment.js Error -cannot Find method moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, momentjs

trying to use moment.js to format date.

I have included the source of the library to the header file.The date object is retrieved from mysql database But when I try to format the date object I get an error that says moment() is not a known method.The library is in the scripts folder.

This is the header file

```html
<?PHP
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php'; 
include_once 'includes/menu.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 
   <script src="scripts/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="scripts/datetime-moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header> 

  </header>

<div class="nav">

<?PHP menuIterms($dbh);
          ?>     
</div>
```

this is the code from the body of page

```js
<?php

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM data_centre_users ");
 
             if($stmt->execute()){
                // output data of each row
                while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['first_name']."  ".$rows['last_name']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['department']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['unit']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['purpose']; ?></td>
                         <td class="center" >
                           <input name="booking_time" type="datetime-local" id="booking_time" value="<?php echo moment($rows['booking_time']).format('MM/DD/YYYY'); ?>" size="15">
                         </td>
   <?PHP                     }
             } ?>
```

This is the error displayed 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have included moment.js which is a javascript library. You can not call it like this. Try php built-in date and strtotime as follow and replace it with your code.

```
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($rows['booking_time']));
```